# how to change the font of the EditText hint in android?

Tags: android, xml, fonts, android-edittext

As I have mentioned in the Question I am trying to change the font of hint in EditText. But I can't seem to make it happen!

this is my code for the the EditText getting the username:

```
<!-- Email Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/input_username_id"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                android:hint="@string/hint_username"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="right" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and here is my java code:

```
_usernameText = (EditText) (findViewById(R.id.input_username));
font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/ir.ttf");
_usernameText.setTypeface(font);
```

this didn't change the font of the hint of the EditText.
I have tried other solutions and nothing changed.
http://chintanrathod.com/customizing-textinputlayout-part-2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Don't**

```
  _usernameText = (EditText) (findViewById(R.id.input_username));
 font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/ir.ttf");
 _usernameText.setTypeface(font);
```

**Do**

```
TextInputLayout   usernameTextObj = (TextInputLayout)    findViewById(R.id.input_username_id));
font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/ir.ttf");
usernameTextObj .setTypeface(font);
```

Answer (score 2):

since your EditText is wrapped in **TextInputLayout** you will have to setTypeface on TextInputLayout object reference